# R: Error: could not find function "tbl_dt"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am running R version 3.3.3
I have `dplyr` version 0.5.0 installed

I am trying to coerce some data into a data table, using the `tbl_dt` function that I thought was in `dplyr`; but R complains that that function isn't there.

My thinking is that the current version of `dplyr` no longer contains `tbl_dt`, but I am unable to confirm that online.

Is `tbl_dt` deprecated? If not, how do I invoke it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tbl_dt() belongs to dtplyr package , you need to install dtplyr

Comment: What is the difference between tbl_dt and as.data.table?  I couldn't find any info on this in the help docs for dtplyr

Comment: As information to later visitors, it could be, that `tbl_dt` is now `lazy_dt`, see: https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/blob/2a3154b05e2a016e495a5a2b07c08736244ed49e/R/step-first.R#L27.